# Changing Admob ID after 1st admob account is disabled.

Tags: android, admob

I have question about admob id.
My admob account has been disabled after voilation of googles terms & conditions,  and now it totaly terminated. I have open new admob id on my girlfriend name on different adress and different pc as well as different bank account,  I've menitized some apps on using new admob id and it will works fine. So my question is that if I use this admob id for my old apps whrer I had broken the rules of google. It is possible to again they disabled my girlfriend account becouse of same package name, screen shot, icon etc. Or it is better to me to forget earning from my old apps and totaly forget the 100k downloads. Please help

And sorry for my English.

Comment: Question is asking for legal advice.

Comment: Yes, because I don't want to take chance again.

Comment: Plz guys solve my problem. .plz give me answer

Comment: Ask a competent lawyer, not a programmer forum.

Comment: Ok but I'm asking only them who have faced this problem

Comment: Don't use girlfriends admob account for your old games. Google will link them and you will get banned again.

Answer (score 0):

Technically you are not supposed to use anyone else's admob account.
Looks like you already have and its working for you.
For your older app it is not worth taking the risk. You can may be change the ads to be served from FAN (Facebook account network) instead of Admob, which will still give you an opportunity to get value of your older app.